# Silverlight 4.0: How to convert byte[] to image?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, arrays, base64, system.drawing

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
```

I want to convert byte[] to image, however System.Drawing.Image is not supported in Silverlight. Any alternative?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to create an ImageSource and assign that to an Image control or use an ImageBrush to set on the background. BitmapImage is located in the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace.

```
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length))
        {
            BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage();
            im.SetSource(ms);
            this.imageControl.Source = im;
        }
```

or for the ImageBrush

```
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length))
        {
            BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage();
            im.SetSource(ms);
            imageBrush.ImageSource = im;
            this.BoxBorder.Background = imageBrush;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to write the imageBytes to MemoryStream using the Write method? Aren't they put in from the ctor? Shouldn't im.SetSource(stream) be im.SetSource(ms)?

Comment: Oh yea, I just reused the original code that he had above for convenience, but now looking at it - it is a bit off.

Answer (score 3):

this code can convert image to byte[]

```
BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
Stream stream = openFileDialog1.File.OpenRead();
BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
currentImageInBytes = new byte[0];

currentImageInBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
stream.Position = 0;
imageSource.SetSource(stream);
```

and this code can convert byte[] to image

```
public void Base64ToImage(byte[] imageBytes)
{

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage();
        im.SetSource(ms);
        img.Source = im;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way:

```
    public static BitmapImage ConvertStreamToImage(Stream stream)
    {
        BitmapImage _resultImage = new BitmapImage();

        _resultImage.SetSource(stream);

        return _resultImage;
    }
```

which uses these name spaces:
`using System.IO;`
`using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;`